# Append and remove element on click

Tags: jquery, dom

Im trying to add and remove div with click.
I succeeded in adding it but cant figure out the **remove** part.

- +Question: Is element completely removed with .remove() from DOM?

**HTML:**

```
<center>
<a href='#' id='gogo'>Add</a>
<div id='sexy'></div>
</center>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var extra="<div class='bass'><a href='#' class='gaga'>Remove</a></div>";

$('#gogo').on('click', function(){


    $('#sexy').append(extra);



});

$('.gaga').on('click', function(){


    $(this).parent().remove();



});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Vmhe2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, `.remove()` will completely remove the element from DOM tree.

---

But, your remove code should look like:

```
$('#sexy').on('click', '.gaga', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();  // as .gaga is anchor, so use preventDefault() 
                         // to stop default page load of browser
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

As you're appending `.gaga` dynamically so you need delegate event handling and you can do it using ***[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)*** method.

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Vmhe2/4/)***

---

#### Note

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event *(aka live)* is:

```
$(StatciParent).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Where, `StaticParent` refers to the parent of `target` element which is not dynamic and `target` is the element to which you need to bind the event.

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
$('#gogo').on('click', function(){

    $('#sexy').append(extra);

    $('.gaga').on('click', function() {
         $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});
```

I have moved remove function right after appending extra div

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the element is completely removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

When you register the event handler, the DOM element has to exist at that moment. If you want it bound dynamically, use delegate(): http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vmhe2/49/

try this :)